# Rabbitmq to Kafka Protocol Translation

Tags: apache-kafka, rabbitmq

I am using RabbitMq in Ubuntu Sever as a cluster. I want to configure Kafka to Rabbitmq. I have gone through below link But no luck.

https://www.confluent.io/connector/kafka-connect-rabbitmq/

Comment: " But no luck." -> can you describe what you did, and what problems you encountered? Did you get an error? what configuration were you using?

Comment: I didn't do any thing For kafka Configuration to Rabbitmq. I didn't understand How to configure Kafka to Rabbitmq.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you need to stream messages from RabbitMQ to Kafka, or the other way around?

Comment: We are using Mqtt Also in our projects from mqtt to kafka we are moving data that is the reason we are planning to take all protacals data to kafka then we will process the data with our frameworks

Answer (score 0):

> I didn't understand How to configure Kafka to Rabbitmq

While there are other tools you could use, that link is for Kafka Connect. It would help if you started by [understanding how to run it](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/userguide.html#running-workers).

To get that Connector, you  would download Confluent Platform & [Confluent Hub Client](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/managing/confluent-hub/client.html), then run the command from that page.

Then find the `connect-standalone` script in the `bin` folder, if you want to run a Standalone Worker

Find configuration options here 
https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-rabbitmq/

Then create a property file and start up Kafka Connect worker based on the first link I gave

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But we are using HDP . we have to implement the same in Hortonworks platform.

Comment: Kafka Connect works with HDP's installed Kafka just fine. You would setup separate servers for runnning a Connect cluster anyway, which is not managed by Ambari